# ember element that is hidden by focus out event is blocking click event

Tags: ember.js

I have an odd conundrum.

It appears that when an element is hidden by a focus-out event ember is unable to attach the corresponding click event that triggered the focus out properly. For example with the code below if the `<a>` tag triggers the focus-out event on the input and the code behind turns `_focused` to `false` then the `selectOpts` event is never triggered. It appears to only happen if the `a` tag is hidden as a result of the focus-out.

Also oddly it does not matter how the `a` tag is hidden either if i do just `display:none` it still also doesn't fire the `selectOpt` action.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    {{input value=value class='form-control' focus-in="focused" focus-out="unfocused" }}
    {{#if _focused}}
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
          {{#each _filteredOptions as |opt|}}
              <li><a href="#" {{action "selectOpt" opt}}>{{opt}}</a></li>
          {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Here is a ember twilldle showing the issue.

https://ember-twiddle.com/6bbdb669d19d7a498e645bb0297f1b46?openFiles=templates.components.input-autocomplete.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.input-autocomplete.hbs

In order to get it to show the issue focus in on the text area and then try to select one of the links that appear below the input. What is supposed to happen is that when you select the link it is to populate the input field with the value.

Comment: If `_focused` is false, none of its sub elements will be rendered, so the action cannot be triggered. Why don't u use `ember-power-select`?

Comment: At the time the element is clicked _focused is true. Power select does not do autocomplete input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `focus-in` instead of both `focus-in` and `focus-out`. So when you click on input `focus-in` event trigger and set _focused to true. Then, in action selectOpt you set value and after that set property _focused to false.

```
<div class="dropdown">
{{input value=value class='form-control' focus-in='focused' }}
{{#if _focused}}
  <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      {{#each options as |opt|}}
          <li>
            <a href="#" {{action "selectOpt" opt}}>{{opt}}</a>
          </li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/if}}
```

input-autocomplete.js

```
actions: {
    focused() {
        this.set('_focused', true);
    },
    selectOpt(opt) {
      console.log(opt);
       this.set('value', opt);
       this.set('_focused', false);
    }
}
```

I didn't include all code for input-autocomplete it's the same as before exxept actions. Also I used options array insted your filter because didn't get any results when clicked on input.

Comment: The user is not required to select a value. It is just a suggested auto-complete field.